# Redirecting an image in Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Lets say i have 2 images A.jpg AND B.jpg.

A.jpg is the old one and whenever someone makes a request to A.jpg, it should redirect to B.jpg. Is this possible?? If yes how do i do that?

Searching for a sol, I found that redirect is only possible if the file type is .html

Here is the code that i was playing with :

```
  var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("MyPublicKey", "MySecretKey");
  var copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest()
                    .WithDirective(S3MetadataDirective.REPLACE)
                    .WithSourceBucket("MyBucket")
                    .WithSourceKey("A.jpg")
                    .WithDestinationBucket("MyBucket")
                    .WithDestinationKey("A.jpg");      

  copyRequest.AddHeaders(new NameValueCollection { { "x-amz-website​-redirect-location", "B.jpg" } });
  var copyResponse = s3Client.CopyObject(copyRequest);
```

Please help,